# With "japanese" input method, unmap kanji selection via the spacebar?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, input-method, japanese

In emacs-26.1, I am enabling the Japanese input method as follows ...

```
(toggle-enable-multibyte-characters 1)
(set-language-environment "Japanese")
(set-input-method "japanese")
(setq coding-system-for-read 'utf-8-unix)
(setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8-unix)
```

This works fine and gives me hiragana characters when I enter their romaji equivalents, but `SPC` is mapped to a selection dialog for kanji characters. I want `SPC` to be mapped simply as `self-insert-command`, and I'd like to remap the kanji selection dialog to a different key sequence.

I tried the following, but it had no effect ...

```
(define-key kkc-keymap " " 'self-insert-command)
(define-key kkc-keymap "\C-^" 'kkc-next)
```

`SPC` still got me into the kanji selection dialog, and `C-^`did nothing.

I'm not sure, but it seems like there is code somewhere in `kkc.el` which forces `kkc-next` to be mapped to `SPC`, no matter what.

Short of completely rewriting some of the code in `emacs-26.1/lisp/international/kkc.el`, is there any way to remap the kanji selection dialog to something other than `SPC`?

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about this, but (1) are you sure you have the right keymap, and (2) have you tried `(kbd "SPC")` instead of `" "`?

Comment: Thank you very much. It turns out that `(kbd "SPC")` does not change the behavior. Concerning the question of the correct keymap: in looking at the code in `kkc.el`, it _seems_ that `kkc-keymap` is the one to use, but I am not sure. I'm hoping someone who is more familiar with the Japanese input method can help.

Comment: PS: it seems like this automatic romaji-to-hiragana encoding is not done via the normal keymap and mode methodologies of emacs. My Japanese-enabled buffer remains in `fundamental-mode`. Also, in `kkc.el`, it seems like there is special logic to explicitly traverse the `kkc-keymap` in a non-standard manner when characters are being typed, even though the mode is still `fundamental-mode`. Anyway, I'm still digging into this and will report whatever I ultimately come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

As defined in `lisp/international/quail.el`, `(quail-conversion-keymap)` returns the keymap which is used for input methods, including the Japanese input method. In this keymap, `" "` (and not `(kbd "SPC")` in this case) gets mapped to `quail-japanese-kanji-kkc`, which causes the input selection dialog to be invoked via `kkc-region` from within `lisp/international/kkc.el`.

So, doing the following to enter the Japanese input method accomplishes what I want ...

```
(toggle-enable-multibyte-characters 1)
(set-language-environment "Japanese")
(set-input-method "japanese")
(setq coding-system-for-read 'utf-8-unix)
(setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8-unix)
;; Enter the kanji selection dialog via `\C-^`,
;; and change the spacebar to simply insert a space.
(let ((qckeymap (quail-conversion-keymap)))
  (define-key qckeymap "\C-^" 'quail-japanese-kanji-kkc)
  (define-key qckeymap " " 'self-insert-command))
```